# Prove that if $Z(G) = \lbrace x \in G: gx = xg \text{ for all }g\in G\rbrace$ then $Z(G)$ is a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

So my challenge is:

> Prove that if $Z(G) = \lbrace x \in G: gx = xg \text{ for all }g\in G\rbrace$ where $G$ is a group, then $Z(G)$ is a group

Unlike this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571214/to-show-that-the-center-is-a-subgroup, I am not asking for a technique to prove this but a check of my proof, i.e. proof-verification.

For the identity, $e$ clearly is in $Z(G)$ and in $G$.

For the inversability, $$gx = xg \iff x^{-1}gx = g \iff x^{-1}gxx^{-1} = gx^{-1} \iff x^{-1}g = gx^{-1}$$

For the Closure, I am not so sure my proof is complete:
$$gx = xg \iff gxa = xga \iff g(xa) = x(ga) \iff g(xa) = x(ag) \iff g(xa) = (xa)g$$

Is my proof complete?

Thanks

Comment: looks good to me!

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: You probably want to prove that $Z(G)$ is a subgroup of $G$, not simply that "it's a group" (any set can be given a group structure). Words matter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [To show that the center is a subgroup](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571214/to-show-that-the-center-is-a-subgroup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think you've got it. Just be sure to mention that associativity is inherited from $(G, *)$, should you be in a situation where you have to mind all the details.

As for the closure part, maybe this style works better (but uses your ideas):

Let $x, a \in Z(G)$. Then, for all $g \in G$, $g(xa)=(gx)a=(xg)a=x(ga)=x(ag)=(xa)g$, and thus, $xa \in Z(G)$.

Feel free to ignore if you're not wild about it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion: a few more clear indications of what you are doing would be advisable.  For closure you need to prove

> if $x\in Z(G)$ and $a\in Z(G)$, then $xa\in Z(G)$.

So start with

> Let $x\in Z(G)$ and $a\in Z(G)$.
>   Therefore $gx=xg$ and $ga=ag$ for all $g\in G$.

and continue

> Hence. . . (following your working above). . . $g(xa)=(xa)g$ for all $g\in G$.
>   So $xa\in Z(G)$.

Short cut: depending on the level of detail required by your instructor, you could possibly take associativity for granted and just write the working as
$$gxa=xga=xag\ .$$

Comment: Thanks! I like both your and Ken's answers, so i will just roll a die to see who gets the accept. Just saying this so you don't get offended, because if I could, I would give it to both of you.